# Compressed files (using Zippy) are corrupted

Tags: ruby, zip

I wrote a function to list the PDFs inside a specific folder and zips them but for some reason the zip contents are corrupted.

The script basically does:
a) Creates a zip file named as `$batch_id` in the `$target_dir` location.
b) Adds a XML named with the `$batch_id(.xml)` to the zip root.
c) Adds all the PDFs found in the `$target_dir/pdf/` folder to the `/pdf/` folder in the zip.

RESULT: the zip is succesfully created, the XML can be extracted, but the PDFs seem to be corrupt (the file size is very small and cannot be opened).

```
def zip_batch
  puts "Zipping batch..."
  require 'zippy'

  Zippy.create("#{$target_dir}"+"\\"+"#{$batch_id}"+".zip") do |zip|
    zip ["#{$batch_id}"+".xml"] = File.open("#{$target_dir}"+"\\"+"#{$batch_id}"+".xml")
    Dir.glob("#{$target_dir}"+"/pdf/*.pdf").each do |filename|
      puts "   -> Adding "+ filename.gsub("#{$target_dir}"+"/","")
      puts filename
      zip[filename.gsub("#{$target_dir}"+"/","")] = File.open(filename)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I found the problem was that the files were not being read in binary mode.

This fixed the problem:

      zip[filename.gsub("#{$target_dir}"+"/","")] = File.open(filename,'rb')

Comment: then please add it as an answer, you can accept then after a while or remove this question, otherwise it stays open

Comment: @peter It is already added as an answer. Do I need to add it somewhere else? (Sorry, I'm quite new here)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem was that the files were not being read in binary mode.

This fixed the problem:

```
  zip[filename.gsub("#{$target_dir}"+"/","")] = File.open(filename,'rb')
```